# Need to refresh drop down after we have inserted newly values in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a Page where I am using 2 user controls. One control is reservation control and other is channel partners control. On reservation control I have a drop down which has all the channel partners. When user has new channel partner he clicks a AddNewChannel link and channel partner comes as pop up and after that user inserts new channel partner into the database. Now my problem is that whan data is inserted into the database I want drop down on reservation to be refreshed and should contain new channel partner. I tried like this:

```
UpdatePanel upnl = (UpdatePanel)Page.FindControl("UpdatePanel1");

if (upnl != null)
    upnl.Update();
```

My drop down on reservation control in in update panel. But it didnt work. Any try to help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using ASP.net or MVC? I assume you want to refresh only the DropDown and not the whole page?

Comment: I am using asp.net C#, I want tor refresh only part of page ie y using update panel..

Comment: When user click the button for adding the new channel, this button should refresh the reservation panel as well.
So to accomplish that, this button should be added as a trigger to the reservation panel.
In this way it'll be updated when a new channel is inserted.

Comment: graumanoz....reservation is a separate user control and channel partner is separate usercontrol both the controls are used on one page....as dropdown isnot directly accessible on channel partner.

Comment: Could you show your markup?  Also, could you show the code where the DropDownList (the one on your Reservation control) is populated?

Comment: Why don't you just add a "Refresh" button on the form? Let the user act wise.

Comment: @user2164964 so what are your thoughts on my answer - anywhere close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumption: Channel Partners user control contains the popup to add new partners. The popup has a Save button (ASP.Net serverside control) with a server side click handler which actually commits the data to the database. Also that your user control includes an additional update panel with an async postback trigger so that when the user saves the new partner the form doesn't postback, but instead makes an async postback**

So generally I use events to allow user controls to talk to each other. In this case you just need to raise an event to say when the new *channel partner* has been created and have your update panel trigged on this event.

### Channel Partners user control.

So I'd add a new event called NewChannelPartnerCreated to the Channel Partners user control.

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> NewChannelPartnerCreated;
```

Also for the Channel Partners user control I'd append to the Save buttons click handler to raise the event once the save has complete successfully.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code that commits new partner to the database

    if (errors == false)
        NewChannelPartnerCreated(this, null);
    else
        // show errors
}
```

### Reservations user control

Amend the Reservations user control to expose a public method to refresh the drop down list and call the update method of the update panel that wraps the drop down list

```
Public void RefreshChannelPartnersList()
{
    ChannelPartnersListUpdatePanel.Update();

    // this databind code might not be needed if you have already have it in the PreRender (not PageLoad)
    ddlChannelPartners.DataSource = YouMethodToGetChannelPartnersFromDatabase();
    ddlChannelPartners.DataBind();        
}
```

### User control container Page

Finally in the code behind of the page that hosts both of the users controls; I'd make the following change that completes the picture.

In the page load you'd want to listen to the NewChannelPartnerCreated event raised by the Channel Partners user control. The event handler simply needs to call the *refresh* method, exposed by the Reservations user control

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewChannelPartnerCtrl.NewChannelPartnerCreated += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(NewChannelPartnerCtrl_NewChannelPartnerCreated);
}

void NewChannelPartnerCtrl_NewChannelPartnerCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReservationsCtrl.UpdateChannelPartnersList();
}
```

### Downloadable Example

Try this http://sdrv.ms/18138yH

Answer (score 0):

Anser was to use unload method of model popup and update from there. Feeling disappointed not getting any answer from this community.....

Comment: I think not getting an answer isn't a poor reflection on the community but a reflection on the quality of question that you have provided. Unfortunately there are hundreds of ways of coding a solution and I think your question leaves the community needing to make a lot of assumptions before attempting to answer your question.